# generate html code in span?

Tags: java, html, jsf

I want to generate some html code for the jsf page I have (I am not on jsp so I cannot use out.print), so I use icefaces component ice:outputText:

```
<ice:outputText id="txtCaptcha" escape="false"></ice:outputText>
```

I successfully find the outputText by id from Java code

```
UIViewRoot root = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
HtmlOutputText icefacesOutputText = (HtmlOutputText) root
.findComponent("mainContentForm:txtCaptcha");
```

and put some html code in it so with Firebug I can view:

```
<span class="iceOutTxt" id="mainContentForm:txtCaptcha" style="height:300px; width:100%;"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=<key>"></script>
<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=<key>" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="">
</noscript></span>
```

Well... I do not understand why it does NOT appear in the html page? Why I can only see the content with Firebug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you (or IceFaces) inserting the HTML after executing some JavaScript/Ajax code? That would explain why it is not available in generated HTML output, but only in the current state of the HTML DOM tree which only JavaScript (and Firebug) can see.

Comment: You are right BalusC. Somehow, Icefaces does not do a full post-back for my form but "rendering occurs into a server-side DOM and only incremental changes to the DOM are delivered to the browser and reassembled with a lightweight Ajax Bridge"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another suggestion:

```
<ice:outputText id="txtCaptcha" value="#{myBean.someHTML}" escape="false"/>
```

then in the getter of the bean `myBean`, you return your HTML code:

```
public String getSomeHTML() {
    return "<span>...</span>";
}
```

As you set the `escape="false"` attribute, it will not escape the HTML characters, and thus it will be generated.